# How to reverse the grouping order in a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to reverse the grouping? For example in the below report, based on user role the grouping should be reversed.

ie.

- **Role A** it should be grouped like **Item** then by **Item Type** and
- **Role B** it should be **Item Type** and then by **Item**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups based on formluas.

For the first group do something like:

```
If {myTable.Userrole}="A" Then
    {myTable.Item}
Else
    {myTable.ItemType}
```

and for the second group, vice versa:

```
If {myTable.Userrole}="A" Then
    {myTable.ItemType}
Else
    {myTable.Item}
```